# Why my Python PySimpleGUI window is not right clickable, so I can paste from my clipboard?

Tags: python, click, pysimplegui

I try to paste data to the window using a right click menu, but this option does not exist at all.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text('Name')],  # main window
        [sg.InputText(key='-NAME-')],
        [sg.Text('Phone')],
        [sg.InputText(key="-PHONE-")],
        [sg.Text('Facebook ID')],
        [sg.InputText(key="-ID-")],
        [sg.Text('email')],
        [sg.InputText(key="-EMAIL-")],
        [sg.Cancel(key="-CANCEL-"), sg.Submit(key="-SUBMIT-")]
        ]
window = sg.Window('Facebook', layout)

while True:  # start here
    event, values = window.read()
    fb_id = values['-ID-']
    fb_name = values['-NAME-']
    my_phone = values['-PHONE-']
    fb_email = values["-EMAIL-"]
    if event == "-CANCEL-":
        break
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click menus for multiline elements are not something that tkinter supplies automatically.  Keyboard bindings like Control A, Control C, etc, are automatically supplied.

This code will give you a simple right-click menu for a Multiline element

It's not yet been added to the official Demo Programs but will be shortly...

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

"""
    Demo - Adding a right click menu to perform multiline element common operations

    Sometimes Multiline Elements can benefit from a right click menu. There are no default menu
    that come with tkinter, so you'll need to create your own.

    Some common clipboard types of operations
        Select all
        Copy
        Paste
        Cut

    The underlying Widget is accessed several times in this code because setting selections,
    getting their values, and clipboard operations are not currently exposed in the APIs

    NOTE - With tkinter, if you use the built-in clipboard, you must keep your program
    running in order to access the clipboard.  Upon exit, your clipboard will be deleted.
    You can get around this by using other clipboard packages.

    Copyright 2021 PySimpleGUI
"""

right_click_menu = ['', ['Copy', 'Paste', 'Select All', 'Cut']]
MLINE_KEY = '-MLINE-'

layout = [  [sg.Text('Using a custom right click menu with Multiline Element')],
            [sg.Multiline(size=(60,20), key=MLINE_KEY, right_click_menu=right_click_menu)],
            [sg.B('Go'), sg.B('Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('Right Click Menu Multiline', layout)

mline:sg.Multiline = window[MLINE_KEY]

while True:
    event, values = window.read()       # type: (str, dict)
    print(event, values)
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    if event == 'Select All':
        mline.Widget.selection_clear()
        mline.Widget.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')
    elif event == 'Copy':
        try:
            text = mline.Widget.selection_get()
            window.TKroot.clipboard_clear()
            window.TKroot.clipboard_append(text)
        except:
            print('Nothing selected')
    elif event == 'Paste':
        mline.Widget.insert(sg.tk.INSERT, window.TKroot.clipboard_get())
    elif event == 'Cut':
        try:
            text = mline.Widget.selection_get()
            window.TKroot.clipboard_clear()
            window.TKroot.clipboard_append(text)
            mline.update('')
        except:
            print('Nothing selected')

window.close()
```

This is how it looks in use....
[image]

Comment: Thanks Mike. Is there a way to show on the screen, inside the window layout, what was insert as the user input?

Comment: @Mike from PSG: something I've been trying to work out, and not sure is possible is how to know which element was the right clicked on? Assume you had a set of sg.Input lines that are added/removed via window.extend_layout / hide_row they sg.Input Keys are dynamically created with an incrementing variable... There appears to be no way to know which sg.input key relates to the right click..